# GetAccessTokenForUserAsync throws an exception

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to call a Web API from a Web App, passing a token for identifying the user.

I'm following the docs here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore

However, when I call the `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` method, I always get an error AADSTS65001, stating that `The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '....' named '...'`.

I really don't understand this error. What kind of consent are we looking for here? The application ID mentioned in the error message is the client app, and I double checked that the scopes accessed from the client app in the API are already consented.

What am I missing? I thought it should be quite straightforward - take the token received by the web app, send it to the web API, and let it authenticate it.

Is there any simple way of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: You might not have access of the app you are trying to access, check with admin account for access.

Answer (score 0):

So for future reference, the problem was that the scopes specified in the `GetAccessTokenForUserAsync` method were not prefixed with the API URL prefix (usually in the form of `api://346363-35262ffe-23cwf3-ve523632t`), and therefore Azure AD assumed I was trying to access my own app, which did not have such scopes.

After I changed the code to include the prefix in the scope, ie. `_tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { $"api://346363-35262ffe-23cwf3-ve523632t/Employees.Read" })` it worked like a charm.